# How do I set up a Debezium SQL Server connector in Kafka without using Docker nor the Confluent Platform on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to capture some changes in a SQL Server database using Kafka in standalone mode.
In this task, the Confluent platform and Docker are not options.

The CDC on source database is already enabled. On the Kafka side, I'm having issues with Debezium connector. I'll describe more details bellow:

--- zookeeper.properties:

```
dataDir=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/data

clientPort=2181

maxClientCnxns=0

admin.enableServer=false
```

--- server.properties:

```
broker.id=0

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1

transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=30000

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

auto.create.topics.enable=true

delete.topic.enable=true
```

---

--- sqlserver-source-connector.properties:

```
name=sqlserver-connector

connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector 

database.hostname=myhostname 

database.port=1433 

database.user=sa 

database.password=mySuperSecretPassord

database.dbname=myDbName 

database.server.name=myhostname

table.include.list=dbo.employes 

database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=myhostname:9092 

database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.fullfillment

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

offset.storage.file.filename=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/connect.offsets

bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

---

--- file-employes-sink.properties:

```
name=file-employes-sink

connector.class=FileStreamSink

tasks.max=1

file=file-employes-sink.txt

topics=myhostname.dbo.EMPLOYES
```

---

When I try to run

```
.\connect-standalone.bat ..\..\config\sqlserver-source-connector.properties ..\..\config\file-employes-sink.properties
```

and also check the connectors that could have been created through the link http://localhost:8083/connectors, here's what I get:

["file-employes-sink"]

That means that I only get to create my sink connector, right?
What about my source connector? Shouldn't it be listed here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `connect-standalone.properties` as the first parameter to `connect-standalone` to configure *the worker*

You then provide your two connector property files to start two *connectors*

You could also use `connect-distributed`, with its properties file, then you'd HTTP POST the two connector configs

---

While Confluent Platform doesn't support Windows officially, it would still work the same. So would Docker

Comment: Thanks for replying. After following your advice, I came across a new issue: "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector." I have already added the parameter plugin.path=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/plugins in my properties file, and Debezium folder is in this path too, but still it's not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what is in your "debezium folder", but as long as you have `plugins/debezium-connector-sqlserver/debezium-connector-sqlserver-[version].jar`, it should work, though I've never used Windows with any Kafka tools

Comment: That was just a space after the value of connector.class parameter. It's working now. Thanks for your help!